# Using overflow:hidden results in a small gap between border and background image

Tags: html, css, overflow

[image: Here is the screenshot]

```css
.el-card {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #EBEEF5;
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #303133;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}

.el-card::before {
    content: "";
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: url("~@/assets/images/grid-card-selected.svg") center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

If I remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `.el-card`, there is no more gap between the border and my image.

How could this happen and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a graphics-related issue like anti-aliasing-related or something. Try opening the page on a different browser. If it still persists, the most straightforward solution would be to set the ::before pseudo element to `right: -1px` and `top: -1px`.

Try setting `border-radius: none` on the `::before` pseudo-element. Since overflow is set to hidden on the main element, the pseudo-element shouldn't exceed its borders.

Comment: I've tried that, only if remove the `overflow: hidden`, or it won't work.

Comment: @NickHopps Try ```border-radius: none;``` on the ```::before``` pseudo element.

Comment: still the same.

Comment: for now the wordaround I apply is to set the overflow as visible and set the inner box as hidden. `overflow: hidden` creates a BFC, maybe someting to do with this?